# Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.NavUtils Message

Tags: android, gradle, appodeal

Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.NavUtils
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present:

android.support.v4.app.NavUtils, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}

### How solve this problem?

if anyone has any ideas of the cause of this problem I would appreciate the share of knowledge. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

### Build gradle project

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'



        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

### Build gradle module

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ru.startandroid.identificationtest"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
     implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
     implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'
     implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.0'
     implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
     implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
     implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
     implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0'
     testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
     androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
     androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
     implementation  'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'
     implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2' //for Inmobi
     implementation name: 'adcolony-sdk-3.2.1', ext: 'aar'
     implementation name: 'mmedia-6.4.0', ext: 'aar'
     implementation name: 'mobvista_alphab', ext: 'aar'
     implementation name: 'mobvista_appwall', ext: 'aar'
     implementation name: 'mobvista_appwallext', ext: 'aar'
     implementation name: 'mobvista_common', ext: 'aar'
     implementation name: 'mobvista_interstitial', ext: 'aar'
     implementation name: 'mobvista_mvdownloads', ext: 'aar'
     implementation name: 'mobvista_mvjscommon', ext: 'aar'
     implementation name: 'mobvista_mvnative', ext: 'aar'
     implementation name: 'mobvista_nativeex', ext: 'aar'
     implementation name: 'mobvista_offerwall', ext: 'aar'
     implementation name: 'mobvista_playercommon', ext: 'aar'
     implementation name: 'mobvista_reward', ext: 'aar'
     implementation name: 'mobvista_videocommon', ext: 'aar'
     implementation name: 'mobvista_videofeeds', ext: 'aar'
}
```